# Why am I getting a redirect loop with Wordpress htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a site-wide redirect from http to https for my Wordpress, and I'm trying to follow this tutorial - https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/12/force-https-pages-wordpress-site/

This seems to work for them, but when I follow it, I get a message saying the website is performing in a way that will never complete (or redirect).

My htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone please help me identify what's causing the redirect loop and how to fix it? I've put it into various testers, which seem to run through it fine. I have no plugins running, and can't figure out what's causing the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I typically add the custom rewrite rules above the default WP ones.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite non www. to www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Rewrite HTTP 2 HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
...
```

As you can see both rules redirect to HTTPS (the first one is applied only if non www. though).

Whenever a request is starting with https://www. the standard WP rulez (which you have posted and which are kept below in your .htaccess file) are applied as wanted.

Comment: Is it okay to have `RewriteEngine On` appear more than once? That's what I thought I was having issues with, copying and pasting bits from different sources into one file.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work, it's causing a message to say there's too many redirects basically. This is a message I've been seeing with everything I've tried to do actually.